# Retrieve through mysql query the 'œ' character in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I'm working on an application for a French client who has its database MySQL, collation Latin1, character encoding swedish_general_ci. I assume that in ISO encoding terms that corresponds to the ISO 8859-15 standard (which is single byte encoding and contains the 'nasty' **œ** character).

In a table 'mytable' there is a column 'mycolumn' which has the following record/row:
"Il est au cœur du débat"
I am doing queries from PHP 5.3, based on keywords that are or are not in this table's comumn. The queries are simple SELECT with LIKE clause and everything returns the right results except when I do this from PHP:

```
$tag = $_GET['search']; // the value of tag is ckecked as "cœ" (I printed in a file)
$res=query("SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `mycolumn` LIKE '%" . $tag . "';");
```

It should return the above "Il est au cœur du débat" result, but, it doesn't (count($res) is zero).
If I just copy the above query (where I replace $tag with "cœ") from the code and paste it directly into phpMyadmin and execute SQL it works correctly, with the row displayed as result. I mention that the accented characters are not an issue.
What am I missing? Thx

Comment: Yes, it is based on mysql_query(). And it works for any other SELECT that doesn't include that character

Comment: @GingerOpariti Try $res=query("SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `mycolumn` LIKE '%$tag%' ");` - SO is not being nice about the backticks around `mytable` WHERE `mycolumn`

Comment: @Fred: that's MySQL recommended syntax. Besides, the œ character is the only one to mess up not the syntax

Comment: @GingerOpariti And what if you were to use its [DEC-OCT-HEX-BIN](http://www.ascii-code.com/) equivalent?

Comment: @Fred: really don't understand ... This character is inside a string that is a part of the SELECT statement, so how "to use"? In fact that is my question

Comment: @GingerOpariti it's a complex problem and I can't give you a definite answer, only suggestions. I've never been in this type of situation before. Another suggestion would be to wrap your query inside braces such as `LIKE '%{$tag}%'";`

Comment: @Fred: I am grateful to your help. No the braces is just a syntax alternative

Comment: @GingerOpariti It's my pleasure. Plus as I mentioned in another comment below, if that character is to be inserted from future posts, then all I can think of is to catch it before it gets inserted in DB using `preg_replace` or other form of character replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) does not contain the OE ligature. Latin-9 (ISO-8859-15) does. UTF-8 OE will be a 2 or 3 byte single character. Note that only a small subset of UTF-8 will be translatable to a single-byte encoding. You need to find out exactly what's stored in the database -- is the text in there actually UTF-8 (multibyte), Latin-1, Latin-9, or something else? Pray that it's not a mixture of multiple encodings! See what a utility like phpMyAdmin displays for the character, and in **what encoding**.Note that the *encoding* of the field does not necessarily correspond to what byte(s) that particular oe character showed up in. If the field is a single-byte encoding, it should accept any input without corrupting it (but won't necessarily display the expected characters).

Once you understand how the data has actually been stored in the database, you can concentrate on how to convert your web page input (presumably UTF-8) into the proper encoding matching what's in the database.

Comment: Phil, I have set at the begining of my post the database encoding schema. I have also addressed your other comments. I know what is in the database as content and encoding. I also know quite well how to use phpmyadmin. I have reached to read and process at character level the string 'cœur' and transform it into 'coeur' (the usual way  it is done in programming) so that I can publish it on a utf-8 encoded html page. The only problem is that the above SELECT, from PHP (not from phpmyadmin where it works ...) returns nada

Comment: If the database **encoding** is Latin-1/ISO-8859-1 (Swedish _collation_ for sorting), you need to first figure out exactly what single or multibyte value this 'oe' ended up being put into the database as. It must be replacing some regular Latin-1 character (or is it multibyte UTF-8?). Presumably someone has specified what the UTF-8 or other input encoding got changed to. Then you can figure out what to change 'oe' to in your query to so you get a match from SQL. Then the final step is to translate the returned query back into UTF-8 or whatever your page presents in.

Answer (score 0):

Is your web page in UTF-8? If so, you will need to [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231819/convert-utf8-to-latin1-in-php-all-characters-above-255-convert-to-char-referenc) it before you can use it. And be sure to at least escape your data before passing it into your query (or use prepared statements). You're open to SQL injection as written.

Comment: Yes, my page is in UTF-8. Could you pls be more specific? I've tried all three types of PHP conversion functions. The problem I have is only and only for the œ character, found on a single byte reprezentation only in ISO 8859-15. All other French accented characters are processed correctly

Comment: Which functions have you tried? And did you try the link I shared in my post? Answers the conversion question

Comment: I've tried utf8_encode, iconv and mb_convert_encoding, with no result for a string like 'cœur'. In the best case they just remove the 'œ' character. My understanding is that in your link it's about converting character by character. My $tag comes from data entry, it is a string, so I would like to know if there is a way to apply a function to that string without any mangling

Comment: @GingerOpariti You can always catch it before it goes in the DB by doing a `preg_replace`